# Lookup dictionary based on python key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in the format:

`mylist1 = [{'model': 'one'}, {'color': 'blue'}, {'age': 23}]`

Is there a way I can look up a dictionary based on its key? For something I want to do something like (pseudocode):

`mylist1['model'] #should return {'model': 'one'}`

The reason why I am not doing `mylist[0]['model']` is because the list elements are not always in that order.

Comment: Are keys unique? In that case, just collapse them into a single dictionary.

Comment: Why are these separate dictionaries in the first place?

Comment: You need to re-think your data-structure here. You've essentially created a very memory-inefficient `list`, with none of the advantages of a `dict` (i.e. constant-lookup time)

Comment: NOT exactly what you want, but related https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collapse your dictionary.

```
d = {k : v for d in mylist1 for k, v in d.items()}

d
{'age': 23, 'color': 'blue', 'model': 'one'}
```

Now, just lookup in constant, `O(1)` time.

```
d['model']
'one'
```

By keeping multiple disjoint `dict`s in the same list, you're defeating their purpose in the first place.

---

If you have multiple possible values with the same keys, use a `dict` of `list`s.

```
d = {}
for dct in mylist1:
    for k, v in dct.items():
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

d
{'age': [23], 'color': ['blue'], 'model': ['one']}
```

Supports multiple values with the same key without overwriting entries, as the previous one would've done.

Comment: @KaushikNP I mentioned in that case that OP should use a dict of lists, or some nested structure.

Answer (score 4):

The pseudocode you provided is impossible unless you subclass (or monkey patch) `list` (otherwise you'd get an error that list indices must be integers and not strings).

However you could write a function such as

```
def find(li, key):
    for d in li:
        if key in d:
            return d
```

It will find and return the first dictionary that contains the given key, and can be easily modified to return a list of dictionaries if the keys are not unique.

## **But**

it looks like you are using dictionaries wrong. Why do you have a list of dictionaries, each having (apparently) unique keys, and not a single dictionary?

Comment: OP has thereby completely defeated the purpose of using dictionaries - if you have to iterate over them to find values.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Indeed

Answer (score 1):

Using `list comprehension` , find all `dictionaries` in the `list` that contain that `key` :

```
>>> mylist1 = [{'model': 'one'}, {'color': 'blue'}, {'age': 23}, {'model': 'two'}]
>>> key = 'model'

>>> [ ele for ele in mylist1 if key in ele ]
=> [{'model': 'one'}, {'model': 'two'}]
```

**NOTE TO OP :** as others have pointed out, its ofcourse quite redundant to have a list of dictionaries; *unless you have dictionaries with duplicate keys*.

Answer (score 1):

```
key = "model"
d = [ x for x in mylist if key in x ]
```

If you want just one match:

```
key = "model"
d = next( x for x in mylist if key in x )
```

Second one uses generator, so it just finds first match and then stops.